# cakephp saving other model data

Tags: cakephp, forms

I have two models

Rest (id, name .....)
Operating_hours(id, open, close, rest_id)

When I try to save a record from Restaurant add form. It saves only the open and the close time but not the reference id at rest_id.

```
$this->Restaurant->create();
if($this->Restaurant->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => 'first'))) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The restaurant has been saved', true));
    //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The restaurant could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the two model files? The problem might be there.

Comment: Do you have the proper relation in the Restaurant model? I.e. Restaurant hasMany Operatinghours and Operatinghours belongsTo Restaurant? And why don't you rename rest_id to restaurant_id?

Comment: @Nik its according to convention. sorry. while typing i did the short form. i found the mistake. there was a validation rule from the baked code for restaurant_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing an insert (since it is an "add"), it is unlikely that you can perform everything in one step, as MySQL would not know the id of your restaurant to save the opening hours. I'd suggest doing the following:

```
$this->Restaurant->create();
if($this->Restaurant->save($this->data, array('validate' => 'first'))) {
    $this->data['rest_id'] = $this->Restaurant->getLastInsertId();
    if($this->Restaurant->OperatingHours->save($this->data, array('validate' => 'first'))) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The restaurant has been saved', true));
        //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The restaurant opening hours could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
    }
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The restaurant could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
}
```

Comment: thanks. there was a validation rule with the rest_id in the model which was not letting it save. :D works now after removing it :D